# python formatting float numbers

Tags: python, floating

my input is 3.23, but when I use float on it, it becomes 3.2,

when my input is 3.00, when I do float on it, it becomes 3.0

when I convert to float from string, I still want it to be 3.00 and not 3.0 
is it possible?
I want to know the code to make it possible, and when I am doing a problem in which the decimal point till 2 digits matter, 3.23 is better than 3.2, for more precision

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964369/quick-python-question Do you happen to be in same class? ;)

Comment: Yes.  It's possible.  What's your REAL question?

Comment: float('3.23') != 3.2 please be more precise here :)

Comment: -1: No code to back up the "it becomes" claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that what you want is to convert a float to a string with the number of decimals that you want. You can achieve that using %.3f (here 3 is the number of decimals that you want to print. For example:

```
>>> print "Value: %.2f" % 3.0000
```

Value: 3.00

Answer (score 3):

Since this thread is first on the words "string formating decimal python", I think it's good to provide a more recent answer :

```
>>> P=34.3234564
>>> string="{:.2f}".format(P)
>>> string
'34.32'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want decimal precision use the python [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module:

```
from decimal import Decimal
x = Decimal('3.00')
print x
```

That prints:

```
Decimal('3.00')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a floating-point number to a desired precision you can use output formatting codes like the following:

Assuming x = 3.125

```
print "%.1f" % (x)    # prints 3.1
print "%.2f" % (x)    # prints 3.12
print "%.3f" % (x)    # prints 3.125
print "%.4f" % (x)    # prints 3.1250
```

This will work in python 2.6 (I think they changed the print function in version 3).

You should also realize that floating-point numbers can only be stored with a certain accuracy, so sometimes you will not get the exact same number back. For example 0.1 may be stored as something like 0.9999999987.